Get specific index for dictionary
I have this lambda function:
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.describe_maintenance_windows(Filters=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Values': ['test']
        },
    ])
    MWId = response["WindowIdentities"]
    return(MWId)

I got below response Response structure:
[
  {
    "WindowId": "mw-0154acefa2151234",
    "Name": "test",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Duration": 4,
    "Cutoff": 0,
    "Schedule": "cron(0 0 11 ? * SUN#4 *)",
    "NextExecutionTime": "2024-08-25T11:00Z"
  }
] 

How do I get the value of WindowId so I can pass it to a variable? I tried below but I am getting "errorMessage": "'list' object is not callable"
mwidvalue = MWId("WindowId")


The response structure is a list of dict => response[0]["WindowId"]

Accessing a dictionary key is one of the most important and most basic functions in Python. It should be covered in every Python tutorial. SO is not a replacement for learning the language basics.

Be aware that your code is a little fragile right now in that a) it doesn't handle exceptions from the call to describe_maintenance_windows and b) it doesn't handle the case where there are zero maintenance windows in the result.

It's a list that contains a dictionary, so you would need to use:
mwidvalue = MWId[0]["WindowId"]

That will return the first element of the list (in your example, there is only one) and then the WindowId element of that dictionary.

As the error you mentioned says, you are working with a list. For that reason, you need to get the element of the list that you want to work on it and then do whatever action you want to do.
In this case, the element inside of the list is a dictionary, so you can use get methods to obtain the element.
MWId[0].get("WindowId")

That shoud be enough.
